# MediaElement.js Flash Fallback IE7 and IE8 seek causing out of memory error

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I have found that using mp4's with flash fallback, is causing out of memory errors in JQuery when you seek ahead in the video and or simply hover your mouse around the progress bar.

I have turned off progress feature and this seemed to fix the issue. Any ideas on why this happening ? Is it something to do with mp4 streaming in flash ??

```
$('audio,video.default').mediaelementplayer({
    // enable debugger
    enablePluginDebug:false,
    // turned off progress
    features: ['playpause','current','duration','volume','fullscreen'],
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    // force iPad's native controls
    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
    // force iPhone's native controls
    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
    // force Android's native controls
    AndroidUseNativeControls: true,
    // turns keyboard support on and off for this instance
    enableKeyboard: false,
    // when this player starts, it will pause other players
    pauseOtherPlayers: true,
    // initial volume when the player starts
    startVolume: 0.8,
    // log error(s)
    error : function(mediaElement)
    {
        console.log('mediaelement problem is detected: '.mediaElement);
    }
});
```